# The qt qml window keeps flickering on mac os bug?

Tags: qt, qml, flashing

The qt window keeps flickering on mac os, but windows does not have this problem, what is the problem? Please see video attachment [text](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/attachment/143390/%E5%B1%8F%E5%B9%95%E5%BD%95%E5%88%B62023-07-23%20%E4%B8%8B%E5%8D%884.52.15.mov)

Don't flicker the window, keep the window normal don't flicker
It is easy to reproduce this problem when I switch the application window and return to the qt program

Comment: this is video https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/attachment/143390/%E5%B1%8F%E5%B9%95%E5%BD%95%E5%88%B62023-07-23%20%E4%B8%8B%E5%8D%884.52.15.mov

Comment: Do the out-of-the-box template apps also flicker?

Comment: If you want help especially on your bugreport you need to share more information. Which version of macOS are you using. Share the demo application that causes the flickering and so on. The developers need to able to reproduce your issue to actually start looking into it.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/attachment/143390/%E5%B1%8F%E5%B9%95%E5%BD%95%E5%88%B62023-07-23%20%E4%B8%8B%E5%8D%884.52.15.mov

Comment: I found the problem. I used the qt version of telegram and the same problem occurred. In my second attachment